# How to clone an UltraGridColumn (Infragistics)?

Tags: c#, infragistics

```
reportGrid = new DataGridView();
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in grid.Columns)
{
    DataGridViewColumn newCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
    newCol = (DataGridViewColumn)col.Clone();
    reportGrid.Columns.Add(newCol);
}
```

I'm trying to mimic some existing code above that works for a DatagridView but for a UltraGrid but not sure how to Clone the column, I looked at CopyFrom as well which works for UltraGridRows.

```
 foreach (UltraGridColumn col in grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns)
 {
      UltraGridColumn newCol = new UltraGridColumn();  //Errror here as well
      //newCol = (UltraGridColumn)col.Clone();
      newCol.CopyFrom(col);

      reportGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns.Add(newCol);
 }
```

Comment: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments, I'm not sure if I need to assign newCol to be a new UltraGridColumn()? Its the clone or copy I'm interested in

Comment: Why are you attempting to clone a column rather than adding a new one to the grid?  What do you gain by cloning the column?  What are you trying to accomplish with the UltraGrid?

Comment: I wanted to clone the column so that it can be displayed on a report, I'm allowing the users to select only certain columns to be displayed so want to copy or clone its contents to a new ultragrid so it can be displayed on the report

Comment: #alhalma: out of interest How do you just add a new column to a Ultragrid?

Comment: Just to be naive, but why don't you simply set the same datasource of the grid to the reportGrid, refactor the InitializeLayout event and then hide the columns not required in the report? By the way, a new unbound column could be added using the `grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns.Add("colName", "Header Text");` or adding a new column to the datasource

Comment: I guess I could do that, can you tell me how I can " refactor the InitializeLayout event and then hide the columns not required in the report?" I can't see a hide method for the ultragrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refactor the **InitializeLayout** method I mean to extract all the code written for this method (usually formatting columns for display or other one time configuration of the grid) and put everything in a different method directly callable from your code.

Then, when your user press the button to print the grid, initialize the gridReport with the same datasource, call the same common code and perform the specific hiding for the columns on the second grid.

This pseudocode assume you have declared two grid (grdMain with the initial data and grdReport to use for printing) also I assume the presence of a ultraGridPrintDocument to start the printing process

```
private void gridMain_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    CommonInitializeLayout(gridMain, e);
}


private void CommonInitializeLayout(UltraWinGrid grd, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
   UltraGridBand b = e.Layout.Bands[0];
   // Now do the customization of the grid passed in, for example....
   b.Override.AllowRowFiltering = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
   b.Override.AllowAddNew = AllowAddNew.No;
   b.Override.NullText = "(Not available)";
   b.Columns["CustName"].Header.Caption = "Customer Name";
   ....... etc ....
}

private void cmdMakeReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This assignment will trigger the InitializeLayout event for the grdReport
    grdReport.DataSource = grdMain.DataSource;
    // Now the two grids have the same columns and the same data 

    // Start to hide the columns not desired in printing
    grdReport.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["CustID"].ExcludeFromColumnChooser =
                                                             ExcludeFromColumnChooser.True 
    grdReport.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["CustID"].Hidden = true;
    // .... other columns to hide.....

    // Now print the grdReport
    ultraGridPrintDocument.Grid = grdReport;
    ultraGridPrintDocument.Print();
}

private void gridReport_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    CommonInitializeLayout(griReport, e);
}
```

Comment: Cheers for that I had to add a line to make this work though, I had to: grdReport.BindingContext = grdMain.BindingContext;

Comment: Yes, right. I was assuming a direct linkage to a datatable or dataset.